# Using diskpart with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

When I use Diskpart within Powershell. I only get 11 characters from the Label. How can I access the full name?

```
$CusHost = "test-svr-101"
[string]$temp = Invoke-Command -Computername $CusHost -ScriptBlock {
    $dpscript = @"
list volume
"@;
    $dpscript | diskpart
}
$vols = $temp -split "\s(?=V)"
```

The output looks like this:

[image: Powershell output]

which is not the full name:

[image: Showing the full name of the disk]

Comment: The equivalent PowerShell cmdlet is [`Get-Volume`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/storage/get-volume) (`FriendlyName` holds the label). It takes permissions into account, so that (e.g.) you won't see boot volumes if you run it from a non-elevated command prompt.

Comment: I think `Get-Volume` is not available on older Windows versions. `Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume | Select-Object -Expand Label` should work, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume
```

As per Ansgar Wiechers comment below.

Comment: It only shows the disks where a drive letter assigned. I'm trying to query the user profile disks.

Comment: In that case use: Get-partition | Select *

Comment: Umm... no. `Get-Partition` does not show volume labels. Use `Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the DOS utility fsutil, located in C:\Windows\system32:

(fsutil fsinfo volumeinfo f:)[0]

Comment: This doesn't show the user profile disk. Am I right?