# How to copy all contents from drive A to drive B while using diskpart & batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I thought exiting diskpart and reentering would work, but it does not. Would really appreciate any suggestions, thanks. Code ist executed from a batch file.

```
LIST volume
SELECT volume 4
SHRINK desired=500
LIST disk
SELECT disk 1
CREATE partition primary size=500
FORMAT fs=ntfs quick
ASSIGN letter=k
EXIT
XCOPY /h /c /k /e /r /y d:\ k:\
diskpart
SELECT disk 1
LIST partition
SELECT partition 3
DELETE partition
LIST partition
SELECT partition 2 
EXTEND
```

Comment: How do you enter into diskpart the first time?

Comment: @echo off 
DISKPART /s A:\folder\TEST.txt 
Through the batch file

Comment: See https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2012/04/replace-diskpart-with-windows-powershell-basic-storage-cmdlets/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54328395/using-diskpart-with-powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the text file TEST.TXT is not equivalent to a bat file. (Not telling you anything new). I would therefore split it into two:

TEST1.TXT

```
LIST volume
SELECT volume 4
SHRINK desired=500
LIST disk
SELECT disk 1
CREATE partition primary size=500
FORMAT fs=ntfs quick
ASSIGN letter=k
EXIT
```

TEST2.TXT

```
SELECT disk 1
LIST partition
SELECT partition 3
DELETE partition
LIST partition
SELECT partition 2 
EXTEND
```

Then a batch file with the following:

```
@echo off DISKPART /s A:\folder\TEST1.txt
XCOPY /h /c /k /e /r /y d:\ k:\
@echo off DISKPART /s A:\folder\TEST2.txt
```

Comment: It works, but is the only workaround to split the txt file?

Comment: I think you should consider using the more powerful powershell.